# Linux permission denied when make log message into file

Tags: permissions, logs

```
sudo date > output.txt
bash: output.txt: Permission denied
```

I want to write log message into file, but the permission denied even I add prefix `sudo`, But when I tried after making `output.txt` file and changing permission to `755`, It works well.

How can I write log meesage without making file and changing permission?

simply like `sudo date > output.txt --chmod 755 ?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date | sudo tee output.txt > /dev/null
```

This works because `tee` opens the `output.txt` and it is running as root. The `> /dev/null` is just to throw away the extra copy that `tee` would send to `stdout`.

The reason why `sudo date > output.txt` doesn't work is that the output redirection (the `> output.txt`) is done *before* the `sudo date` is started, and so runs with the current access rights.

A different approach would be to change the permissions on the current directory to allow the current user to create files. Doing this would mean that `date > output.txt` could work without needing `sudo`.